# QGIS Version 3.6 Raster Calculator

Tags: qgis-3, raster-calculator

In the previous version of QGIS when you loaded a multiband color image into raster calculator the bands were separated.

In version 3.6 I am only seeing 1 band how do I get the other bands displayed ?

Answer (score 2):

I think it is a bug in QGIS 3.6, if you load the raster into QGIS 3.4.5 Long Term Release (LTR), it will be loaded correctly with all the bands available in single raster:

QGIS 3.4.5 LTR:

[image]

QGIS 3.6:

[image]

You can report a bug following this page here: [Bugs, Features and Issues](https://qgis.org/en/site/getinvolved/development/bugreporting.html). My advice is to use QGIS 3.4.5 LTR as it is a stable version.

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm this has been fixed in QGIS 3.7.0 (the current development version) and so will be in QGIS 3.8 when it comes out.

Comment: Could you please provide a link to a source supporting this claim? (bug tracker, etc)

Comment: I haven't been able to find this in the bug tracker, but tested it out on my own machine. I replicated the error in QGIS 3.6 (and had the same problem which brought me here in the first place!). Then I confirmed it didn't happen in 3.4.5, nor in 3.7.0.